# use of fields of runing form in another form

Tags: c#

I create a form that contains a public field and a button. The button creates another form and shows it as dialog. Can I access to the public fields on main form? the main form run in main method like this:

```
static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }

public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public int number;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (new SecondForm()).ShowDialog();
        }
    }

public partial class SecondForm : Form
    {
        public SecondForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Method()
        {
            //How can I access to number?
        }
    }
```

I don't want use constructor because there are a lot of variables in mainform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method that sets the owner of the created form.

```
secondForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

usage in  your second form:

```
var temp = ((MainForm)this.Owner).number;
```

Comment: Thanks. this is the best way. In this case I can read or write the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of the `MainForm` class and you can use it access all the public variables in the class

```
MainForm f = new MainForm();
int a = f.number;
```

This might not really work as it will create a new instance of the `MainForm` class and you might not get the desired result, so a better will be to make `number` static.

```
public static int number;
```

Then you can use

```
int a = MainForm.number;
```

Comment: That will be a totally different instance than the one that created the second form.

Comment: @Downvoter, I agree this is not the best answer but does it make it worthy of a downvote?

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes. I would love to improve??

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just do:

```
var form = new SecondForm();

form.<property> = <value>
// ...

DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog(); 

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you don't want to use the SecondForm constructor to pass all of those variables from MainForm. Why not just create a class to hold the values and pass the class instance between the two?

```
public class FormData
{
    public int number;
    public int anotherInt;
    public FormData(int num)
    {
        number = num;
    }
}



public class SecondForm : Form
{
    private FormData myData;
    public SecondForm(FormData data)
    {
        myData = data;
    }
}



public void AMethodInMainForm()
{
    FormData d = new FormData(this.number);
    d.anotherInt = 26;
    SecondForm frm = new SecondForm(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a public number in SecondForm

```
public int number;
```

Then before you show SecondForm try this:

```
SecondForm f2 = new SecondForm();
f2.number = this.number;
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Then you can access your number inside of your SecondForm.This works if you call number variable several times from your methods inside of your form2.But if you want access number in Form1 whenever you want,you should define it as `Static` and `Public`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your number as public static int number and then:

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    public SecondForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void Method()
    {
        MainForm.number = // something
    }
}
```